# Как на один Observer подписать несколько subscribe

Tags: angular2, observer

Есть сервис, который провайдерится в главном модуле. Идея в том, чтобы при изменении объекта this.userSettings через метод  setSettings подписчики обсёрвера получали новый объект (новая ссылка на объект). Подпись происходит в разных компонентах через высзов метода у данного сервиса getSettingsObservable.

```
    constructor() {
        this.userSettingsObservable =  new Observable((observer: Observer<UserSettings>) => {
            this.userSettingsObserver = observer;
        });
    }

    getSettingsObservable() {
        return this.userSettingsObservable;
    }

    setSettings(path: string) {
        this.userSettings = _.set(this.userSettings, path, value);
        this.userSettingsObserver.next(_.clone(this.userSettings));
    }
```

Примеры подписи на Observable в компонентах:

```
ngOnInit() {        
    this.userSettingsService.getSettingsObservable().subscribe(
        (userSettings) => {
            this.userSettings = userSettings;
        }
    );
}
```

Вопрос в том, что subscribe срабатывает только в одном компоненте, в последнем, который подписался. Как сделать так, чтобы сработали все?

Спасибо

Если поможет, вот код сервиса: https://github.com/pakhuta/siarhei.pakhuta.angular2/blob/master/src/app/shared/user-settings.service.ts#L41

а это одно из мест подписки на Observable (именно оно и срабатывает): https://github.com/pakhuta/siarhei.pakhuta.angular2/blob/master/src/app/weather/weather.component.ts#L43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно такой же вопрос задал на английском stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491808/how-did-several-subscription-on-one-observable

Вместо Observable, предложили использовать BehaviorSubject

```
this.userSettingsObservable =  new BehaviorSubject(this.userSettings);
this.userSettingsObservable.next(_.clone(this.userSettings));
```

И всё в огне )))) все подписчики срабатывают!